# Using jquery datatables. Why isnt paging working?

Tags: jquery, datatables, paging

It is also showing ALL of the records instead of '11 of 14 out of 14' for example.. How do I communicate to send only 10 at a time ? I used this article as a tutorial

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part

```
    public ActionResult GetCurrentErrorsAJAX(JQueryDataTableParamModel param)
    {
        List<StepInstanceError> allCompanies = new List<StepInstanceError>();
        allCompanies = InstanceErrorExpert.GetAllErrors();

        IEnumerable<StepInstanceError> filteredCompanies;
        filteredCompanies = allCompanies;

        var sortColumnIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request["iSortCol_0"]);
        Func<StepInstanceError, string> orderingFunction = (c => sortColumnIndex == 1 ? c.FilePath :
                                                            sortColumnIndex == 2 ? c.Notes :
                                                            c.Notes);

        var sortDirection = Request["sSortDir_0"]; // asc or desc
        if (sortDirection == "asc")
            filteredCompanies = filteredCompanies.OrderBy(item => orderingFunction);
        else
            filteredCompanies = filteredCompanies.OrderByDescending(item => orderingFunction);

        var displayedCompanies = filteredCompanies;

        var result = from c in displayedCompanies
                     select new[] { Convert.ToString(c.StepInstanceErrorID),
                                    Convert.ToString(c.StepInstanceID),
                                    Convert.ToString(c.ErrorRow),
                                    Convert.ToString(c.Notes),
                                    c.FilePath,
                                    c.Notes,
                                    Convert.ToString(c.DateCreated)
        };

        return Json(new
        {
            sEcho = param.sEcho,
            iTotalRecords = allCompanies.Count(),
            iTotalDisplayRecords = filteredCompanies.Count(),
            aaData = result
        },
                    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

<script>
$(function () {
    var RefreshErrorTable = function () {
        var oTable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "Errors/GetCurrentErrorsAJAX",
            "bProcessing": true,
            "aoColumns": [
                            { "sName": "StepInstanceID" },
                            { "sName": "ErrorRow" },
                            { "sName": "FilePath" },
                            { "sName": "Notes" },
                            { "sName": "DateCreated" }
            ]
        });
    }

    RefreshErrorTable();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For server-side processing, DataTables also passes `iDisplayStart` and `iDisplayLength`.

Your query should include this to limit the number of rows returned.  Your example page shows this:

```
var displayedCompanies = filteredCompanies
                        .Skip(param.iDisplayStart)
                        .Take(param.iDisplayLength);
```

Pagination (bPaginate) in DataTables should be enabled by default. The DataTables site is excellent and may be of some help: http://www.datatables.net/usage/features